# Spring configuration file in web.xml

Tags: spring

I'm loading my spring configuration file in web.xml file. The spring file contains many beans. How can I get the bean name in my class. Is their any way to get the bean name without providing the path name.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>configDir</param-name>
<param-value>D:/akatte/config</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>springConfig</param-name>
<param-value>spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="foNasShare" class="com.katte.galaxe.FoNas">
<property name="fname" value="arvind"/>
<property name="lname" value="katte"/>
</bean>
```

Pojo class

FoNas.java

```
class FoNas
{
//getter and setter
}
```

Now tell me how can I access the bean name (context.getBean("foNasShare")) in my class. spring-config.xml file is already loaded in web.xml, i don't want to load the xml file one more time. The problem is spring bean is loading but the value of the getter and setter are setting to null.

Comment: not sure what you are asking, can you show your a code sample of how you are providing the path name?

Comment: I think the issue here is proper understanding of Spring configuration and CDI in general. I suggest you start reading the Spring guides which guide you step by step. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview

Comment: When you are defining your beans in your xml you should provide the full qualified class name, that's the way it is, there is no configuration of the configuration.

Comment: I have already given, and the bean is loading properly, but I want to access particular bean, so that I can set and get the value of getter and setter.